# Differences between compilers in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

In Cygwin a search for g++ shows:

- gcc-g++
- mingw-gcc-g++
- mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++

What are the differences between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binaries built with Cygwin's `gcc-g++` link against `cygwin1.dll` which is an implementation of the POSIX API for Windows.

`mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` is instead part of the [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php) toolchain which builds *native* Windows applications that do not depend on Cygwin. The `mingw-gcc-g++` on your system is probably either a symlink to this, or is the version that produces 32-bit binaries.

You can verify this difference by inspecting the import tables of a "hello world" program built with each using `objdump -x hello.exe`.